# Updating Ubuntu but come across error

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, updates

I was trying to update my ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 via command line (update manager wasn't displaying the new release). However, right after I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`, the command line gave me this:

```
 Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 145, in <module>
 fetcher.run_options += ["--mode=%s" % options.mode,
 AttributeError: type object 'DistUpgradeFetcherCore' has no attribute 'run_options'
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and make sure you have the following two lines:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
```

After making sure you have these lines, get yourself updated again and re-try the release upgrade script:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
do-release-upgrade
```

P.S.  change your country code..Like here it is gb for Great Britain.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you added information generalizing the second and third lines of your answer to the case of someone who doesn't live in Great Britain, by substituting the relevant 2-character nation code for the string "gb".

Comment: @karel...Ohh yes certainly...thanks for poinitng it out.